# Use of clock signal in expression not supported

Tags: verilog, signal-processing, vivado

```
module manenc(inp,clk1,out);
      input inp,clk1;
      output reg out;
      always@(posedge clk1) begin
        out<=inp^clk1;
      end
endmodule
```

When I run Synthesis for this code in Vivado, it fails and shows:
 **[Synth 8-27] use of clock signal in expression not supported**

Also in a different case when I change the **always** block to **always@(posedge clk1 or negedge clk1)** it shows : **ambiguous clock in event control**.
What to do?

I'm trying to do manchester encoding, any other methods to achieve that will be appreciated.

Comment: You have to make a pure combinatorial circuit: `assign out = inp ^ clk1;`

Comment: It says concurrent assignment to non-net **out** is not permitted

Comment: Remove the 'reg' from the output: `output out;`

Answer (score 0):

Think about this logically, your always block's sensitivity list is triggering on the edge of `clk1`. That means the always block's logic is run when `clk1` is *transitioning*. If you were allowed to read the value of `clk1`, in theory it would be unpredictable. In reality it is dependent on how the hardware is actually synthesized.

The value of a signal that is transitioning is undefined, so Verilog will not compile something that does not make sense.

For Manchester encoding, what you want to do is latch the output to the negated value of the data you want to send on the rising edge of the clock, and flip it on the falling edge of the clock. [Oldfart's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59278499/use-of-clock-signal-in-expression-not-supported#comment104765737_59278499) using the combinational logic `assign out = inp ^ clk1;` accomplishes this goal, and there is no need to trigger on the edge of a clock signal.

Answer (score -1):

you can like this "always@(*)"